# How to get onclicklistener for action bar title and subtitle android

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

How to add action bar title and subtitle onclicklistener pragmatically like g mail and whats app [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `custom action bar` to add Buttons or TextViews like all other layouts. This is good **[Tutorial](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/)** You can add whatever you want And styling it too. You can edit the action bar with this **[Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html)**

Comment: I want to add a titile to action bar not to window.

Comment: @rajahsekar By that tutorial you can create your own action bar. I'll Edit my answer to add more resources